# History of 8 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.*****

Comment: I think this question could best be phrased as "What are some online resources that discuss what happened today in Jewish history?" I don't think this community should build duplicate content of information that is in many other places.

Comment: I would like mi.yodeya to be the online source as to what happened today in Jewish history.

Comment: There did not seem to be enough interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This date in 1961: Adolf Eichmann sentenced to death in Israel.

Comment: Sentenced or executed?

Comment: Sentenced. He appealed his conviction, but the conviction was upheld, and he was executed on 27 Iyyar 5722 (May 31, 1962).

Answer (score 1):

The yartzeit of R' Moshe David Valle, a foremost student of the Ramchal.